# admob banner doesn't not get shown

Tags: android, admob, banner

I know this have been discussed many times but I couldn't menage to make this work :(. I really tried but I didn't make it.

I have add the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.0.4.jar to my libs folder and I add it to build path.

What else should I do ? I do not see my banner, it never get shown

I guess I do something very stupid but I can not realize what

this is my activity

```
package com.google.ads.example;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class BannerEssentials extends Activity{
  private static final String MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID = "123";

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Lookup R.layout.main
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    // Create the adView
    // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);

    adView.loadAd(request);            
  }
}
```

this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.google.ads.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BannerEssentials"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

this is my layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling your project against android API 13? Check out [admob requirements](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html):

> Requirements
>   The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).

If this does not help, try download and use the latest admob sdk from their official website.

Comment: Only the newest version, 4.3.1, requires you to get and compile against Android 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add admob banner in xml file( http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html )

And remember that you won't always see ad in applicatio, even if everything works fine(read what is a fill rate)

Comment: well , I sow it ones and again I start the app like a 30 times in a row and the banner doesn't get shown.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID` to your actual publisher ID?  If not, you need to go to the [AdMob](http://www.admob.com) website, and sign up and create a site/app to get your publisher ID.

FYI, 4.0.4 is a pretty old version of the SDK.  I would recommend upgrading to 4.3.1 instead.  4.3.1 requires a couple new configChanges in your manifest and requires you to compile against android-13 (4.0.4 does NOT), but it is a more stable and is a more well supported version.  You can find documentation on integrating 4.3.1 [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html).

Comment: it is little strange for me, first I need to upload the app to the market and then I get my publisher ID, am I right ? cause first it requires a url(path) to the app uploded to market, and then gives me the publisher ID, am I missing somethig ?

Comment: If your app is not in the market yet, you can use `http://` according to the tooltip next to the market url input.  I suppose it's not completely intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add your app on the admob site. It will ask you for the name and what type of ad banner or interstitial. Mine was not showing even though I had publisher ID, until I manually added it and hit the finish button at the bottom of the page.